# ArrayStoreException when calling List#toArray() on a List returned by Hibernate

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate

I am trying to convert the `List` returned by Hibernate to an `UserDetails[]` array as follows:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
List<UserDetails[]> oo = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM `userdetails` WHERE 1 ").list();
System.out.println(oo.size()); // Until here it works fine and it shows me the rows I asked in my query.
UserDetails[]us = oo.toArray(new UserDetails[oo.size()]); // Here it throws java.lang.ArrayStoreException
session.close();
```

However, it throws a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: thx for the tip !!!  it didnot work as session.creatSqlQuery(..) , but i tried to changed it to session.createQuery(..) and it worked , i just changed this line  List<UserDetails[]>  oo=session.createQuery("FROM UserDetails where userId=1").list();    thogh do you have any idea how to make session.createSQLQuery(..) work ?

Comment: are sure about List<UserDetails[]>? or is it List<UserDetails>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly print the list :

```
for(UserDetails list: oo){
    System.out.println("Result"+ list.toString());
}
```

Or get Specific data

```
for(UserDetails list: oo){
    System.out.println("Result"+ list.getId());
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers the concrete question. Please elaborate.

Comment: from my understanding may be requirement is to get user details.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html